# How to check Internet connectivity in my Google map application (Android)

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

how to put network validation on Google Map,its working good when internet is up or WiFi is On.But not working when Internet is down

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-detect-internet-connection-status/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1560788/how-to-check-internet-access-on-android-inetaddress-never-timeouts

Comment: first u check the net connection if connection here than open activity outher wise open dialog u have not net connection also have code to check net connection

Comment: i am already checking internet connectivity and also WiFi status in my another project but don't know how to do in google maps

Comment: check if net is no abliable than open some Toast net is not here

Comment: yes i am showing but its working fine when wifi is off but not working when wifi is on but internet access is down

Comment: your net connectiin is not working proper also check net connectiion in bath way like mobile data and wifi connection

Comment: Do u have any example code ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try this. I hope it help you.

```
public static int TYPE_WIFI = 1;
public static int TYPE_MOBILE = 2;
public static int TYPE_NOT_CONNECTED = 0;


public static int getConnectivityStatus(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (null != activeNetwork) {
        if(activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI)
            return TYPE_WIFI; 

        if(activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE)
            return TYPE_MOBILE;
    } 
    return TYPE_NOT_CONNECTED;
}

public static String getConnectivityStatusString(Context context) {
    int conn = NetworkUtil.getConnectivityStatus(context);
    String status = null;
    if (conn == NetworkUtil.TYPE_WIFI) {
        status = "Wifi enabled";
    } else if (conn == NetworkUtil.TYPE_MOBILE) {
        status = "Mobile data enabled";
    } else if (conn == NetworkUtil.TYPE_NOT_CONNECTED) {
        status = "Not connected to Internet";
    }
    return status;
}
```